# Can I disable the Print and Fax feature when embedding DocuSign via the API?

Tags: docusignapi

I use the DocuSign SOAP API to present users with pre-filled documents to be signed. It works great except there is a "Sign on Paper" button available. Is there a way to remove that?

I looked all over the Dashboard and the API and all I've found was the EnableWetSign property of the EnvelopeInformation but that didn't seem to do anything.

I'm calling CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates and then RequestRecipientToken

Thanks!

Comment: I'll research this more and let you know what I find, but I'm pretty sure you should be able to hide the button...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I was actually testing wrong - this is working just fine for me.  All I do is set **EnableWetSign** in the request body to *false* and I'm able to hide the SIGN ON PAPER button.

I have been testing with PHP code (which is not a type safe language) and I was mistakenly setting EnableWetSign = "False", which is the string False not the boolean value for false (0).  If I set EnableWetSign to false it hides the button for me, and setting it to true enables the button, just as expected.  Please check your request and make sure that you are correctly setting its value.  Not sure what language you're using but maybe you're making the same mistake I was?

To disable the Sign on Paper button:

```
EnableWetSign = false
```

To enable the Sign on Paper button:

```
EnableWetSign = true
```

And here is what the request body of a REST API signature request from template call would look like

```
{
"accountId": "123456",
"enableWetSign": "true",
"emailSubject": "Testing Sign on Paper Button",
"emailBlurb": "This comes from PHP",
"templateId": "B977F511-CAB0.......................",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "roleName": "Signer1"
    }
],
"status": "sent"
```

}

Comment: Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: I'm using c# and the SOAP API, so Visual Studio generated all the API related classes for me. I set EnableWebSign in an EnvelopeInformation like this: 

var envelopeInformation = new EnvelopeInformation
{
    AccountId = _docuSignSettings.AccountId,
    EnableWetSign = false
};

then I pass that to CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(). VS made the property a bool based on the web service description. I just did a test and changed the code generated by VS, replacing bool with string, and it made no difference. I still see a Sign on Paper button...